# Better approach to docker images

Tags: docker

I'm new in docker so I want to know what is the better approach to use it. I have a Project that needs three components to work:

- Jboss server application
- PostgreSQL
- A spring boot application

So, based on it my questions are:

1) Should I have one docker image for each component mentioned above? If yes, why not just put all together? My idea of docker is simplify the deploy of a application so put all together will make easy to install this app in another environment, right?

2) If yes (one docker image per component), spring boot is just a "Java -jar" command is really necessary have a docker image to it?

3) In case of PostgreSQL should I have the image with all my database structure and data or just vanilla PostgreSQL without anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions

> 1) should I have one docker image for each component mentioned above ?
>   If yes, why not just put all together? My idea of docker is simplify
>   the deploy of a application so put all together will make easy to
>   install this app in another environment, right?

It is best to put them on a separate components so that:

- You can **isolate cases**(will help you in debugging)
- You can **selectively scale(horizontally)** specific **stateless** components when you run on k8s or docker-swarm
- You can set **hardware limit**(RAM, CPU, etc) per component
- You have **different base images**(might be useful for optimizations)
- You want to **build & test** your components independently

List goes on

> 2) if yes (one docker image per component), spring boot is just a
>   "Java -jar" command is really necessary have a docker image to it?

Please check the list mentioned above (why it's best to separate) **if it fits your use case.** Note that adding it to existing components **will affect your scaling strategy**

Example - you run 3 instances of **jboss component with spring boot app**, you will spawn 3 instances for both of them w/c you might not want.

> 3) in case of PostgreSQL should I have the image with all my database
>   structure and data or just vanilla PostgreSQL without anything?

I would recommend that you mount your structure & data to the **host volume**, so that it doesn't get lost when the image is restarted. [see example](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L20) so i'll recommend using vanilla postgres

I hope this helps you in some way

Comment: On point 2, you should definitely build a Docker image that includes your actual application.  (Especially if, as hinted in the answer, you're considering a Swarm or Kubernetes deployment, where developer-oriented setups that inject code from the host won't work.)  If there's a prebuilt image and the only thing you actually need to provide is a command line then you can use it, but you probably need a custom image that `COPY`s the jar file in.

Comment: @DavidMaze i agree. since OP mentions that he already had a built jar file. I also would consider building the jar file & executing it inside a base image, w/c i mostly do with node apps. not entirely sure it's the best way to go with java, though i've seen some projects go with the later https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L6

Comment: Thank guys, your answers was very usefull for me. I will accept as correct.